# Dojo - Append into a dijit.layout.contentPane

Tags: javascript, append, dojo

I have loaded content into a content pane.. I would now long to append addition html content into that pane however there does not seem to a an append method..

I do not want to overwrite the content of the pane with set.("content", html), so how would you go about appendin?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no special method for doing this, but you can append nodes to the ContentPane instance's `containerNode`.

For instance, to use `dojo.place` to add some additional node(s) to a ContentPane instance `cp`:

```
dojo.place("<div>More HTML</div>", cp.containerNode);
// (places as last child by default)
```

Comment: How can i do this in a declarative form in the Markup itself? I have multiple instances of dojo titlepane and I would like to add some markup on the right side of the titlepane.